# Is there a difference between to be "on" and to be "running" for a dyno?

Tags: heroku

https://www.heroku.com/pricing says that:

1. a *free* dyno "Sleeps after 30 mins of inactivity, otherwise always on depending on your remaining monthly free dyno hours."
2. a *hobby* dyno is "Always on"
3. in case of *hobby* dynos: price is $7/month, and "You pay for the time your dyno is running as a fraction of the month."

My app will get approximately 5 requests per day which it will serve in 3-4 milliseconds each.

I think about changing from free dynos to hobby dynos to avoid sleeping.
How much will I pay?

Am I right that it is only 5x4x30 milliseconds = 600 milliseconds running time in a month which is **approximately $0?** Or should I pay the whole $7/month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also wondering this myself.  There's no clear answer on Heroku's website.  The so called price "calculator" doesn't allow you to customise the number or type of dynos, let alone enter a estimated number of running minutes.

Judging by some of the comments on forms, I'm guessing it's the full $7 per month but it would be great if this could be clarified.

**Answer**: The price is $7 per month and there is no option for the dyno to sleep.  Dynos can be turned off but this potentially disables functionality on the deployed application.

**Also Note**: You can't alway mix dyno types so you might have to pay for a worker dyno in addition to web dyno.  This can be a real sting when you've been testing/developing with free web and worker dynos.  So the jump is not necessarily from $0 to $7, but $0 to $14 per month.

Comment: I asked Heroku Support and will post their answer here. :)

Comment: I got this answer from Heroku Support:

"There is no difference between 'on' and 'running' = two different words for the same meaning. The only difference would be when it comes to Free Dynos: Free Dynos can sleep sometimes. So you can have a Free Dyno that is sleeping (as opposed to running) even though the dyno is technically on.

Paid dynos run 24/7, so the cost for a single Hobby Dyno would be $7.00/month whether there is any traffic or not. However, you can turn the dyno off whenever it's not needed as a way to trigger pro-rating and avoid billing for any time when the dyno was off."

Comment: To put it in a simple way: there are three states for a dyno: "off", "sleep", "on=running". State does *not* depend on actual traffic. Free dynos can sleep (in fact they will after no traffic for half an), hobby dynos cannot sleep. Thus, hobby dynos have to states: "off" (cannot accept traffic, no payment) and "on=runnung" (can accept traffic, should be payed for). You can turn a hobby dyno "off" os "on=running" whenever you want. As you usually want to serve requests continuously, you have to have your hobby dyno "on=running" 7/24, so you will pay $7/month for it.